# Mysql Group by specific time intervals

Tags: mysql, database, group-by

Is there anyway to group by specific time intervals for example, i have this type of table :

```
invoice_id  due_date    invoice_balance
4           2019-02-04  192
5           2019-03-18  0   
6           2019-03-18  3
7           2019-04-24  30392   
8           2019-04-25  47.5
```

Now i have many such records and i want them to group by specific date intervals ( 
today , today+7 day , 7dayto30day, morethan30days ) with sum of amount total :

Expected Results :

```
total  date between
2000   today
2000   today+7 day
2000   7dayto30day
2000   morethan30days
```

so i tried something like this :

```
SELECT SUM(invoice_balance) as sum,invoice_id, due_date 
FROM `my_invoice_master` 
GROUP BY if(due_date between "2019-02-04" and "2019-04-26",0,1),if(due_date between "2019-07-05" and "2019-07-09",0,1) 
ORDER BY u.meta_value asc LIMIT 0 , 10
```

But it doesn't work, is there anyway to return result with those specified date intervals ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(case 
        when due_date = current_date then invoice_balance 
        else 0 
      end) as `today`,
  SUM(case 
        when due_date between current_date + interval 1 day and current_date + interval 7 day then invoice_balance 
        else 0 
      end) as `today+7 day`,
  SUM(case 
        when due_date between current_date + interval 8 day and current_date + interval 30 day then invoice_balance 
        else 0 
      end) as `7dayto30day`,  
  SUM(case 
        when due_date > current_date + interval 30 day then invoice_balance 
        else 0 
      end) as `morethan30days`
FROM `my_invoice_master`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function IF:

```
select invoice_id, invoice_balance, 
  IF(DATEDIFF(DATE(due_date), DATE(NOW()))<=7
    , IF(DATEDIFF(DATE(due_date), DATE(NOW()))>0, 'today+7', 'today')
    , IF(DATEDIFF(DATE(due_date), DATE(NOW()))<=30, '7dayto30day', 'morethan30days')
  ) as due_period
from my_invoice_master
```

This query show you all records by periods. If due_date will be less then today it gets you 'today'.

---

If you need sum invoice_balance by **invoice_id** use this:

```
select invoice_id, sum(invoice_balance), 
  @due_period:= IF(DATEDIFF(DATE(due_date), DATE(NOW()))<=7
    , IF(DATEDIFF(DATE(due_date), DATE(NOW()))>0, 'today+7', 'today')
    , IF(DATEDIFF(DATE(due_date), DATE(NOW()))<=30, '7dayto30day', 'morethan30days')
  ) as due_period
from my_invoice_master
group by invoice_id, @due_period
```

---

If you need sum invoice_balance by period use this:

```
select sum(invoice_balance), 
  @due_period:= IF(DATEDIFF(DATE(due_date), DATE(NOW()))<=7
    , IF(DATEDIFF(DATE(due_date), DATE(NOW()))>0, 'today+7', 'today')
    , IF(DATEDIFF(DATE(due_date), DATE(NOW()))<=30, '7dayto30day', 'morethan30days')
  ) as due_period
from my_invoice_master
group by @due_period
```

Comment: I think this is what i need but result is somehow incorrect, could you tell me what you added third and fourth parameter in IF condition ? like 'today+7', 'today'  i don't get this. thank you :)

Comment: IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false). I made tree: value can be less or equal 7, or greater than 7.

Comment: If value is less or equal 7 then check condition if is it greater than 0. If is greater then show text 'today+7', else (if value is less or equal 0) show text 'today'

Comment: if value is greater 7 => check if value is less or equal 30 then show text '7dayto30day', else (values is greater 30) show text 'morethan30days'

Comment: Thank you for explaining, however code is not working as expected since it returns sum of whole table's invoice_balance instead of selected group, i managed to do this by just using 5 query instead of one (sadly), but thank you for reply and explanation.

Comment: This queries return 1 group & only sum of invoice_balance of this period. Periods don't intersect. Do you need sum of invoice_balance only today UNION sum of invoice_balance at today+tomorrow...+(today+7days) UNION sum of invoice_balance at (today+7days)+...+(today + 30days) UNION sum of invoice_balance (today + 30days) + (today + 31days).... That data from today will be at today & (today+7days)?